# Magento 2 - How to use jQuery $ in script injected with requireJs?

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs, magento2.3.4, requirejs-config.js

I try to include a script and use jQuery in it by using `$` instead of `jQuery`

**THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml**

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'fotorama',
        'fotorama_zoom'
    ], function ($) {

        zoom_test();    // Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

    });
```

**THEME\web\js\fotorama\zoom.js**

```
function zoom_test()
{
    jQuery(".selector").css("color", "red");    // Works

    $(".selector").css("color", "red");    // Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
}
```

**THEME\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            fotorama: 'js/fotorama/min'
            ,fotorama_zoom: 'js/fotorama/zoom'
            ,slick : 'js/slick'
        }
    }
    ,shim: {
        'fotorama': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
        ,'fotorama_zoom': {
            'deps': ['fotorama']
        }
        ,'slick': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

How can I use jQuery by using `$` in **zoom.js** ?

Comment: Reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score -2):

Initialize Component From Your Template.

```
Using the <script type="text/x-magento-init"> ... </script> tag
```

***Reference URL:***
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Comment: Can you give me an example which fits to my question please? Not sure how to solve it with the information you gave me.